# Customizing vhost config with nginx/traefik ingress controllers

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a service that serves several /locations. I would like to make a single location /how/very/special reachable by any IP while keeping every other /location accessible only to a list of trusted IPs (which is trivial to do when you can

What is the best-practice way to achieve this via traefik or ingress controllers? Is a sidecar nginx the only way to add this logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using Nginx ingress controller in Kubernetes as standing in documentation https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#user-content-whitelist-source-range

> You can specify allowed client IP source ranges through the
>   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation. The
>   value is a comma separated list of CIDRs, e.g. 10.0.0.0/24,172.10.0.1.
>
> To configure this setting globally for all Ingress rules, the
>   whitelist-source-range value may be set in the NGINX ConfigMap.
>
> !!! note Adding an annotation to an Ingress rule overrides any global
>   restriction.

So as default you should put your trusted IP CIDRS in Nginx ConfigMap and override that rule only for `/how/very/special` by setting CIDR to 0.0.0.0/0